# Magento - Linking Products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

My product is a Cloth. When the prduct is chosen he can also Stitch the cloth so i have created a configurable product named Stitch. How to link the Cloth and Stitch. So when a user buys Cloth he can finish it there or go further for stitching. How to accomplish this. Pls Help. Im a total noob in magento.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a custom option for the stitching, because the stitching is an augmentation of a stock item, not the composition of to stock items.

For an example, see [WesternShirts.com](http://www.westernshirts.com/womens-western-short-sleeve-shirt-cross-cut.html#custom_options), which uses configurable products to represent shirt sizes (stock items) for a given style, but which allows for customization via custom options.

If you need to implement the same custom options again & again, it would be advisable to use an extension to link & manage the custom options.